# How to get connection password from LINQPad script file?

Tags: linqpad, password-recovery

I have a LINQPad script file `*.linq` and there is a password for the database connection. 
How can extract the password? (It looks like a binary data encoded by Base64.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQPad encrypts the password using DPAPI. So you can extract it only if you saved the .LINQ file on the same machine as the same user.

If this is the case, you can extract it by opening the .LINQ file and changing the query to this:

```
Connection.ConnectionString
```